# MongoDb parallel arrays index and namespaced data

Tags: mongodb

In a system with some different webpages and only 1 db/collection for them I used the next document format to be able to find "visible" entities in a specific webpage:

```
{
  "node_id": 4,
  "parent" : 3,
  "parents": [ 1, 2, 3 ],
  "web": {
    "A": {"visible": true},
    "B": {"visible": false}
  }
}
```

The bad thing about that query is **the number of indexes**, I need minimum an index for each "webpage" so I reached easily the **64 limit**.

```
.ensureIndex({"web.A.visible": 1});
.ensureIndex({"web.B.visible": 1});
```

So if I need all entities **visible** in **web A** that has **entity 2 has an ascendant** I have the next query:

```
.find({ "parents": 2, "web.A.visible": true });
```

To reduce the number of indexes I rewrited it to the next format (as suggested here: [generic indexes](http://edgystuff.tumblr.com/post/47178201123/mongodb-indexing-tip-3-too-many-fields-to-index-use)):

```
{
  "node_id": 4,
  "parent" : 3,
  "parents": [ 1, 2, 3 ],
  "visible": [
    { web: "A", value: true},
    { web: "B", value: false}
  ]
}
```

Then I can have only one index:

```
.ensureIndex({ "visible.web": 1, "visible.value": 1 });
```

And use the next query:

```
.find({ "visible": { $elemMatch: { "web: "A", "value": true } } });
```

What happens now? I can't include the "parents" condition in the index because "**visible**" and "**parents**" are both arrays and I get an **parallel array exception**.

```
.ensureIndex({ "visible.web": 1, "visible.value": 1, "parents": 1 }); // ERROR
```

Anyone knows a good architecture to accomplish this, having only one collection for all websites?

Comment: A mesh-like data structure with lots of references between documents is really not a good fit for MongoDB, because you will need a large amount of queries to get all the data you need. You should either reconsider your data structure or use a more fitting technology, like a graph database.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generic indexes or namespaces in MongoDb indexes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575074/generic-indexes-or-namespaces-in-mongodb-indexes)

Comment: So therefore just because you **did not** get an answer yet, does not make it "okay" to ask the **same** question in "slightly" different way.

Comment: @NeilLunn it's not the same, I need different answers. This is for "paralell arrays" in this arquitecture. The other one is for searching alternative data arquitectures.